# Sending Email with Python: Body text over multiple lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, email

I'm looking to loop through an index and create a string to be placed into the body of an email. There will be a comparison between values in two lists to determine whether they are to be added to the string.

I need the string to be displayed over several lines (one for each iteration which meets the criteria) but it's currently applying it as a single line of text in the actual email.

This is the email def:

```
def Emailer(message, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32   

    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.GetInspector 

    index = mail.HTMLbody.find('>', mail.HTMLbody.find('<body')) 
    mail.HTMLbody = mail.HTMLbody[:index + 1] + message + mail.HTMLbody[index + 1:]
    mail.Display()
```

This part is what is used to create the string:

```
body = ""
for i, buyer in enumerate(buyers):
    priceO = pricesOLD[i]
    priceN = pricesNEW[i]
    if priceN > priceO:
      body = body + buyer + "\n"

if len(body) > 0:
  Emailer(body,'subject','email@address.co.uk')
else:
  print("No Matches")
```

Comment: You want a newline after each iteration?

Comment: Yes. When I print the result it is on a new line for each one, however once it goes into a new email it is all one line so the line break don't appear to be recognised.

Comment: use <br> instead of "\n"... that is HTML tag for a line break

Comment: Thanks Peter, feel like a rookie for missing that out in testing. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

The issue was solved by way of replacing `\n`s with `<br>`s.

Comment: Perfect answer.